# GitLab.com Download Counter

Tags: git, statistics, repository, gitlab

I uploaded a GIT repository at GitLab.com, everything seems to work fine.

But I cannot find download statistics. For me this is an essential feature, and GitLab.com hosting would be insufficient without it.

Did I miss something? Can anybody tell me how to get a counter for the number of downloads on GitLab.com?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They probably don't keep that information.  Why is it important to you?  Maybe there's something they do keep track of that you can use as a proxy?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I've lots of projects which I want to upload one by one. The counter is important since I have to manage my time. It doesn't make sense to spend time on updating projects that have no downloads/users. As I said, for me it's essential. And it's a standard feature on all other hosting providers. It's hard to believe that it's not available on GitLab.com?

Comment: I don't think github has that feature either so I wouldn't go as far as common.  If you want to know which projects get the most use, you could go by how many issues there are in the issue tracker or how many stars/forks a project gets.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Unfortunately there's nothing in the sense of my initial question. I know what I need. I know that GitHub has that feature. I know that GitLab keep that information. (It's mentioned in the terms and conditions, anyhow they generate their stars rating.) I'm not looking for a discussion, but for a solution. Again, it's hard to believe that GitLab lacks of simple basic features. If this is really the case, then GitLab would be unusable (at least for me). Hopefully (for GitLab, their users and me), I missed anything and somebody tells us how to get the counter values.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, as of today you can get the last 30 days' http fetch statistics using the REST API as detailed here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/project_statistics.html with

`GET /projects/:id/statistics`

where `:id` is the URL-encoded path of the project.

For instance

```
curl -X GET 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/username%2Fmy-repo/statistics' -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XYZ"
```

Comment: To clarify this example:  `username` may be the name of your project (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding). E.g. in my case (for project lightmeter, repo controlcenter):

`curl -X GET 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/lightmeter%2Fcontrolcenter/statistics' -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: foobar-y3"`

Comment: The stats returned via this API endpoint have limited use: they include all pulls and clones, but only those made via HTTP, and there's no breakdown, deduplication of users (eg unique users), or exclusion of CI/CD pulls, as far as I can see. So I'm seeing inflated stats there which make the simple totals provided poor indicators.

Answer (score 2):

A [similar question](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/121) was asked in the [Gitlab support tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum). The answer was, in March 2015:

> I'm sorry, but we don't provide download statistics for files uploaded to GitLab.com

You would need to run your own instance of [Gitlab CE](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) and setup your own statistics if you would like to track usage like this. Gitlab EE [switched](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/27/gitlab-switches-to-piwik-analytics-to-free-the-javascript/) from Google Analytics to [Matamo](https://matomo.org/) for tracking users, but they just don't expose that information to end-users on Gitlab.com, probably for privacy reasons.

A [feature request for this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21743) was created on the Gitlab CE issue tracker in September 2016, was noted as "a reasonable request" by the GitLab product VP and added to the "Backlog" in January 2018, and was marked "Accepting Merge Requests" in April 2018.

Comment: It seems that many people is asking for the same, but looks as if they don't want to do it really. Not nice to keep blinded for project  utility. Currently searching for other place to put my projects.

Comment: I dunno, really. It seems to me they care about the feature, and they have it in their backlog. They just haven't gotten around to make it work for users across the board. It's encouraging to see they have paying users wanting the feature as well, which bodes well for the future. Honestly, I have never really used that feature that much on GitHub either, so it's mostly a curiosity for me.